# Invalid Syntax на ровном месте

Tags: python

Почему-то возникает ошибка `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` в месте, где по идее не должна была бы возникать:

```
randlist = {buildblock(random.randint(3,5)): buildblock(random.randint(3,15)), buildblock(random.randint(3,5)): buildblock(random.randint(3,15)}
```

Ошибка указывает на закрывающую скобку `}`. Я что-то сделал не так?

Comment: {buildblock(random.randint(*a)): buildblock(random.randint(*b)) for a, b in [[(3, 5), (3, 15)]]*9}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не закрыт последний `buildblock(`, перед закрывающей скобкой поставьте одну круглую скобку.

Comment: Чёртова рассеянность. Спасибо.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin, не за что.

Comment: @AimX поэтому такие вещи нужно записывать лесенкой ;)

Comment: @andreymal, а я так ошибку и нашел :D

Comment: (ой, я должен был в начале коммента @JamesJGoodwin упомянуть, но умудрился промахнуться))